# Wordpress, woocommerce payment gateway logs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I want to know if there would be a way to find out the history of a refund made via a 3rd party payment gateway plugin that uses Woocommerce.

Where do I begin if it is possible? I already messaged the plugin provider. I want to see if I could get it started before they reply.

More details. The refunds we made have failed, Woocommerce says it was successful. I want to investigate where the point of failure might be.

Answer (score 2):

WooCommerce provides logs for transactions if you have enabled `Log Debug Messages` for the specific payment gateway provider (and also hoping that payment gateway provider is also providing logs).

To view the logs, you can go to WooCommerce >> Status >> Logs. And then, select the payment gateway from the dropdown and see what’s in there.